# saltstack: use a Python module in both states and pillar

Tags: configuration-management, saltstack

I have a custom module with a function that i can use in my states like this

```
{% set myvar = salt['mymodule.myfunction']() %}
```

Now I want/need to use it in my pillar. I have tried calling it the same way but I got an error

```
Jinja variable 'salt.loader.LazyLoader object' has no attribute 'mymodule.myfunction'
```

Is there any way to declare this module and function as valid in pillar?

Thanks

**edit**

The actual function is a simple regex to convert the minion ID to a short form of it. I finally implemented the actual functionality with Jinja in both states and pillar, and it works.
I want to use it in states and pillar to be able to load a .sls file if it exists to override default setting with per-minion ones.

So my problem is actually solved but the question behind: how to have a (execution) module that can be loaded in states AND pillar, is still relevant i think. I may rename my question.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing exactly what that function does, and if a pillar is the proper place.

Comment: Could you describe what you actually do when you say use it in your pillar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pillar compilation happens on the master, not the minion. This means that modules only available in the `salt://...` tree (e.g. in `salt://_modules`) cannot be used inside pillar files.

In order to use the module in a pillar file, it must also be made available to the master. In the default configuration, this should be possible by copying the module to `/var/cache/salt/master/extmods/modules`. In order to avoid having to maintain the modules in two locations, one might simply add a symbol link:

`ln -s /srv/salt/_modules /var/cache/salt/master/extmods/modules`

Depending on the values of the `extension_modules` and `module_dirs` options in `/etc/salt/master`, the actual path that has to be used might be different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand why exec modules are not available in pillar, and even if this solution seems a little hacky it may still be a good one. We are currently in the process of moving to pillarstack, so if I need it I'll check if it still works.

Answer (score 0):

This might not exactly be the right solution but there is a mechanism within Salt for generating pillar data by calling [external pillar](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/external_pillars.html) interfaces. Which allows you to use any information that is defined outside of salt. Note that you will need to updated the `ext_pillar` option in your salt-master config to configure the `ext_pillar` interface to run.

For a full list of available ext_pillar functions see: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/tree/develop/salt/pillar

Comment: I know about ext_pillar and I don't think it solve my problem. I want to be able to call a Python execution module from both states and pillar.